# confusion matrix of pickled random forest model

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle, random-forest, confusion-matrix

Is it possible to recunstruct the full confusion matrix of the out-of-bag validation only with the model saved as pickle-dump?

`mymodel.oob_score_` reports an OOB score of 0.75682

I found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13151/randomforestclassifier-oob-scoring-method) that is possible to extract the predicted labels for this model like this:

```
pred_train = numpy.argmax(mymodel.oob_decision_function_,axis=1)
```

But are the train labels also somewhere saved in the model-file or not?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you exported with `pickle.dump()`, but in general, if you only exported the random forest, then no.

`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier` only has [these attributes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and the ground truth is not one of them.

`oob_decision_function` only stores an array of size (`n_samples`, `n_classes`) so you cannot get them from there. There are no other attributes that store the oob ground truth.